# Django - can you explain this?

Tags: django, django-forms

I have three models:

1. `System_Contact`
2. `System`
3. `Contact_list`

The `Contact_List` model has two fields: `contact` and `sys` and, not surprisingly, is just a manyToMany model to associate a list of contacts to each system. I have `modelForm` for adding a new contact to the system's list of contacts:

```
   class Add_Contact_Form(ModelForm):
       class Meta:
           model = Contact_List
           fields = ('contact',)
```

Simple, right? My confusion is this: Even thought the `Contact_List`    model has many *many* duplicate `contacts` (because one contact can    be associated with many systems) each contact is only displayed once    within the form's `Select` widget.

Why?!

I mean, this is a great default behaviour for my purposes, but I want    to make sure this is actually the **correct** default behaviour that    I can rely on, not some random error I have done that just happens to    work out for me now.

Comment: Duplicate contacts go in, unique contacts come out. Can't explain that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not that it's default behaviour, it's that the select widget in your contact_list form is displaying all of the entries that are from the contact table.

Every model is a table in the database, therefore you have 3 tables:

- ContactTable - where every row in the table is a person
- SystemTable - where every row in the table is a computer (for arguements sake)
- ContactListTable - where every row is a mapping between a system and a list of users

If this is what you are trying to do, you should have the following:

```
class Contact(models.Model):
    name = ...

class System(models.Model):
    type = ...

class ContactList(models.MOdel):
    system = models.ForeignKey(System)
    contacts = models.ManyToManyField(Contact)
```

This means that every row in the ContactList table is a relationship between a particular machine from the system table and a list of contacts from the contact table

Comment: OOoohh..... *slaps forehead* Of course! I should have known that. Thanks for the help!